# GET vs POST when clicking on a link or typing a URL?

Tags: http, security, web, browser, websecurity

Why it’s a security feature to prevent using POST when clicking on a link or an image in a website or requesting a URL, why do we always use GET in these cases?

Comment: What makes you believe it's a security feature? A source would be helpful. There are restrictions in terms of what HTTP methods can be done under what circumstances, but I don't believe that preventing other HTTP methods via links is because of security.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a solid source, it was a homework question that I did understand. I looked for sources to prove that GET is safer in such cases, but this info wasn't mentioned anywhere.

Comment: is it possible you confused a few things? For example the GET request is called a 'Safe' method because it doesn't have any side-effect. keyword: "HTTP Methods, safely, idempotence". POST can have security risks. Another good keyword to search might be "CSRF".